# How to use hostname rather than IP address for website

Tags: ubuntu, ip, webserver, hostname

I've set up a VirtualBox VM which has an apache webserver running. I've created a webpage and I can navigate to it via the IP address on devices in the lan. However I want to use a hostname rather than an IP address. I've used /etc/hosts and put the hostname next to the IP address, and on the VM it loads the website, but when I try another device on the lan it cannot go to the website using the hostname, only by the IP address.

How can I get other devices connected to the lan to go to the website by using the hostname?

Comment: Search google for "What is DNS"

Comment: Every device needs /etc/hosts setup for that to work. That's setup on the remote device accessing the server, not the server. That's the easy way to do it unless you have a lot of devices.

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of devices and it wouldn't be practical setting up each device for this

Comment: If you cannot set up DNS, is puppet or ansible a possibility?

Comment: Or use `dnsmasq` and point your hosts to it.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about setting up dns, is this to be set up on the VM machine?

Answer (score 1):

If the hostname of the computer where web server runs is `myhost`, then you can access to that domain using `myhost.local`.

Try writing `http://myhost.local` to the browser.

For course, this works only if the computer running the browser and your server are in the same local network.

Comment: My VM has a webserver and the website  can be accessed by my phone use the IP address of the website. I have changed the /etc/hosts in on the webserver to let says 123.com but I cannot access 123.com on my phone, I can only access this in the VM's web browser. I need to be able to access 123.com on my phone

Comment: Changing /etc/hosts in the computer where web-server is running won't affect how you access the computer from outside. One option is to modify /etc/hosts of all the devices (including you smart phone) where you want to use 123.com rather than the IP address. This is not a flexible solution. A better option is to setup a DNS server that provides the correct IP of your VM when you enter 123.com from any device on the local network. [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/331052/how-to-serve-multiple-domains-from-one-computer-in-a-local-network) might be handy.